# Python Tkinter - resize widgets evenly in a window

Tags: python, user-interface, grid, tkinter, resize

I have a small test Python app as I am learning both Python and Tkinter and I am trying to figure out how to evenly resize a grid of labels in a window.  I would like to make a large grid of different colored squares so I'm using labels with a background color set to make the squares.  I would like to resize the squares automatically when the user expands the window out and then have them resize and scale down to all be the same size as the window is decreased in size.

Something like this:

[image: Default "square" size. Opens up at this size by default.]

That resizes and scales evenly like this:

[image: Size when the window is expanded in size.]

In other words: each label should all scale uniformly as the window scales.  I'm not even sure if I'm using the correct terms with "window" and "widget".  But I'm placing labels on a gui.

Test code I'm using to try to get this to work:

```
    import Tkinter

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        label = Tkinter.Label(self,anchor="center",bg="green")
        label.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')

        label2 = Tkinter.Label(self,anchor="center",bg="black")
        label2.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='EW')

        label3 = Tkinter.Label(self,anchor="center",bg="red")
        label3.grid(column=2,row=0,sticky='EW')

        label4 = Tkinter.Label(self,anchor="center",bg="purple")
        label4.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky='EW')

        label5 = Tkinter.Label(self,anchor="center",bg="blue")
        label5.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky='EW')

        label6 = Tkinter.Label(self,anchor="center",bg="yellow")
        label6.grid(column=2,row=1,sticky='EW')


        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title("Test App")
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Give all rows and columns the same non-zero weight.

For example:

```
self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
self.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
self.grid_columnconfigure(2,weight=1)
self.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
self.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!  I looked but could not find a "default" setting for ALL rows and columns.  Do you know if this exists or will I need to add the "self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)" and "self.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)" for all columns and rows separately?

Comment: You will need to do it individually for each row and column

Answer (score 12):

Completing the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24654428/4919040) provided by [Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley), the code for solving it in python 3 is the following.

Note that one option to manage the proportion for which the window resizes is setting the weight parameters for functions `grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)` and `grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)` to different values.

```py
import tkinter

class simpleapp_tk(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        label = tkinter.Label(self,anchor="center",bg="green")
        label.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='NSEW')

        label2 = tkinter.Label(self,anchor="center",bg="black")
        label2.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='NSEW')

        label3 = tkinter.Label(self,anchor="center",bg="red")
        label3.grid(column=2,row=0,sticky='NSEW')

        label4 = tkinter.Label(self,anchor="center",bg="purple")
        label4.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky='NSEW')

        label5 = tkinter.Label(self,anchor="center",bg="blue")
        label5.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky='NSEW')

        label6 = tkinter.Label(self,anchor="center",bg="yellow")
        label6.grid(column=2,row=1,sticky='NSEW')


        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title("Test App")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: One option to manage the proportion for which the window resizes is setting the weight parameters to different values.

Comment: Your solution was helpful. A follow up question. What if the widgets were arranged in packs. it seems widget.pack() doesn't have sticky as an option