# How do I make the size of my widgets or my Frame proportional to the window?

Tags: python, tkinter

As the title says, I would like to know how to make the size of my widgets or my Frame proportional to the window.

Comment: This question is way too broad. There are many ways to make the size of widgets proportional. You should work through a basic tkinter tutorial so that you can understand the three basic ways of adding widgets to a window: `pack`, `grid`, and `place`. All have options to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `grid` geometry manager, along with giving non-zero weights to your rows and columns through the `frame.grid_rowconfigure` and `frame.grid_columnconfigure` methods.

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24654428/7051394) from Brian Oakley.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the size increasing along with the window, I have two methods of doing that. Please select the one that suits your requirement from the examples below:

1) This method changes the dimensions of your frame as you change the size of the main window. Note that the `fill=BOTH` and the `expand=True` arguments work **only** with the `pack` method. You can use `padx` and `pady` to keep the widget smaller than the main window but keep in mind that other widgets will be placed the same distance away from your widget.
Note that `padx` and `pady` work only with `pack` and `grid` methods.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
myframe = Frame(root)
myframe.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

2) Using this method you can change the dimensions of the widget as you wish. You can either make the width of the widget proportional to the width of the main window, or the height, or both. You can also do some simple addition/subtraction if you wish to change the dimensions of the widget along with the dimensions of the window, except, the size of the widget will be smaller than the main window. You can pass `padx` and `pady` as arguments to make the widget smaller than the window but keep in mind that other widgets will be placed the same distance away from your widget.
Note that `padx` and `pady` work **only** with `pack` and `grid` methods.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
myframe = Frame(root)
myframe.pack() #in this technique, you can use any method (pack/place/grid). 
               #because it's not important which method you use to put your 
               #widgets into the window if you use this technique.
root.update()
myframe.config(width=root.winfo_width()) #doing this will keep the width of your frame
                                         #proportional to the width of the main window.
                                         #you can do the same with the height.
```