# Creating a scale-friendly window in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am trying to fit a program I have written using Tkinter onto a 3.5 inch Raspberry Pi LCD. X windows don't fit on the Raspberry Pi LCD properly, so my best bet is having my Tkinter window resizable. I can make it so that the window is resizable, however the widgets do not adapt; they just go off the screen as it resizes. I am wondering how I can make it so that the widgets will dynamically scale according to the window size. With the current code I have they do not move or shrink, especially the images. I also can't access buttons at the bottom of the window in any way. I've tried applying grid_rowconfigure and grid_columnconfigure to each individual widget, and adding stickies, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
from tkinter import *

class QuizGUI:
        def __init__(self, root):
            self.root = root
            self.root.title("Quiz")

            self.canvas = Canvas(self.root)
            self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N + S + E + W)

            self.img = PhotoImage()
            self.img_label = Label(self.canvas, image=self.img)
            self.img_label.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=N + S + E + W)

            self.description = Label(self.canvas, text='test')
            self.description.config(font='12')
            self.description.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky=N + S + E + W)

            for i in range(0, 10):
                self.root.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
                self.root.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

    def main():
        quizroot = Tk()
        quizgui = QuizGUI(quizroot)
        quizroot.mainloop()

    main()
```

Comment: @abarnert I've edited it to add the main(). I'm not sure what else you're expecting, I've removed most functions from the class except for what is used to display widgets in the window. I wouldn't consider the widgets that I'm trying to make dynamically scalable "irrelevant".

Comment: @abarnert Then I've reduced it to two widgets only. The point is that I can't get the sizing under control. The window size is usually determined by the image, nothing adapts to resizing, etc.

Comment: @abarnert It runs in an IDE now.

Comment: Anyway, I think the problem is probably the fact that you're configuring one row and column of each grid with a weight of 1, but leaving the rest at 0, and then stickying everything in all four directions, which means everything but the top and left is just going to move southeast if you grow the window and stay there if you shrink the window. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644339/python-tkinter-resize-widgets-evenly-in-a-window) if that doesn't make any sense (I know this stuff isn't well documented for tkinter).

Comment: Also, doesn't that `font='12'` make it pick some hardcoded default font, so there's no way to scale the label visibly? (You could put a border or fill on it to see that it's scaling, but that isn't helpful for your actual program, just for debugging.)

Comment: @abarnert So I should set the weight for all row/columns I'm using? I've updated the question to reflect what I've tried, however I don't see any effect. Do I have to remove the stickies?