# Creating list in grid view using Tkinter Python

Tags: python, list, tkinter, grid

I am trying to create a grid view listing of product using Tkinter in python, can you please tell me how can I do this

I try to do this using `grid(row, column)` but this also not worked

I want to add a product list like this, I have tried it but not succeed

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644339/python-tkinter-resize-widgets-evenly-in-a-window

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Tkinter - resize widgets evenly in a window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644339/python-tkinter-resize-widgets-evenly-in-a-window)

Answer (score 1):

For you to grid the items you want like that you need to use the `grid()` method.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label

root = Tk()

colors = ['yellow', 'red', 'blue', 'green']

# first create the labels or any other widgets you need and grid them
for i in range(len(colors)):
    Label(root, bg=colors[i], width=50).grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='NSWE')
    
    # then configure the weight of each widget so as for them to resize dynamically
    root.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1) # each row has the same weight
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # column 0 where the labels are also has weight = 1



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You shouldn't have put the ` root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` in the `for` loop. It needs to run only once.

Comment: @TheLizzard you're right